# Problemas con Gulp y Localhost:300

Tags: localhost, gulp

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Visual Studio Code, todo va bien, pero al momento que quiero usar GULP en la terminal para que me compile, la pagina se me cae y no me muestra nada, si vuelvo a escribir en la terminal php -S localhost:3000, me funciona, pero su pongo GULP se vuelve a caer, como lo puedo solucionar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.